# SQL: how to get the results from a varying loop

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, view

Requirement: If a customer has more than one visit in a 31-day period, include only the first visit. For example, if a customer has an visit on January 1 then include the January 1 visit and do not include visits that occur on or between January 2 and January 31; then, if applicable, include the next visit that occurs on or after February 1. Identify visits chronologically including only one per 31-day period.

```
CustomerID  VisitID VisitDate
1              1    1/1/2016
1              2    1/2/2016
1              3    1/31/2016
1              4    2/1/2016
1              5    7/1/2016
```

I need the first entry for a customer in 31 days period, so in the above case my result query should show only two entries

```
CustomerID  VisitID VisitDate
1              1    1/1/2016
1              4    2/1/2016
1              5    7/1/2016
```

is there a way to get this done using a stored procedure.

DECLARE @A TABLE
(CustomerID INT,VisitID INT, VisitDate DATE)

INSERT INTO @A VALUES('1' ,'1' ,'1/15/2016')
                    ,('1' ,'2' ,'2/2/2016')
;WITH A AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MONTH,CONVERT(DATE,VisitDate))) order by VisitDate)
row_id,CustomerID, VisitId,VisitDate FROM @A )
SELECT CustomerID, VisitId,VisitDate FROM A WHERE row_id = 1

In the above script the result entry should only be '1/15/2016', as the date difference between '1/15/2016' and '2/2/2016' is less than 31 days

The SP which you gave worked for first two entries, can you please help with the below requirement. I swear this will be my last query

1. ('1/15/2016'), -- ----- (This is 1st valid visit)
2. ('2/2/2016'), --(This is invalid visit, as this visit occurs within 31 days from 1st valid visit )
3. ('3/2/2016'), -- ----- (This is 2nd valid visit as its occurring after 31 days from 1st valid visit)
4. ('3/4/2016'), -- (This is invalid visit, as this visit occurs within 31 days from 2nd valid visit )
5. ('3/15/2016'), -- (This is invalid visit, as this visit occurs within 31 days from 2nd valid visit )
6. ('7/5/2016'), -- ----- (This is 3rd valid visit as its occuring after 31 days from 2nd valid visit)
7. ('8/1/2016'), -- (This is invalid visit, as this visit
   occurs within 31 days from 3rd valid visit )
8. ('8/7/2016') -- ----- (This is 4th valid visit, as this visit occurs after 31 days from 3rd valid visit)

Comment: Column VisitDate' data type? Which dbms are you using? (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time. Also most products have their own versions of stored procedures.)

Comment: "in 31 days period" starting from what? Can you mean more specific? Also can you show us some code?

Comment: here is the requirement:If a customer has more than one visit in a 31-day period, include only the first visit. For example, if a customer has an visit on January 1 then include the January 1 visit and do not include visits that occur on or between January 2 and January 31; then, if applicable, include the next visit that occurs on or after February 1. Identify visits chronologically including only one per 31-day period.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this one:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (CustomerID INT,VisitID INT, VisitDate DATE)
DECLARE @B TABLE (CustomerID INT,VisitID INT, VisitDate DATE)
INSERT INTO @A VALUES('1','1','1/15/2016'),  ('1','2','2/2/2016'), 
('1','3','3/2/2016'),  ('1','4','3/4/2016'), ('1','5','3/15/2016'),
('1','6','7/5/2016'),  ('1','7','8/1/2016'),  ('1','8','8/7/2016') 

DECLARE @starter INT = 0,@counter INT=0,@CustomerID INT,@VisitID INT, @VisitDate DATE,@total INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @A)

WHILE(@starter<@total)
BEGIN
SELECT @CustomerID=A.CustomerID,@VisitID=A.VisitID,@VisitDate=A.VisitDate,
@counter = ISNULL((DATEDIFF(DAY,B.VisitDate,A.VisitDate)+@counter),0),@starter = @starter + 1
FROM @A A LEFT JOIN (SELECT VisitID+1 VisitID,VisitDate FROM @A 
WHERE VisitID=@starter) B ON A.VisitID = B.VisitID WHERE A.VisitID = @starter+1
IF( @counter = 0 OR @counter > 31)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @B SELECT @CustomerID,@VisitID,@VisitDate
    SET @counter = 0
    END
END

SELECT * FROM @A -- your table
SELECT * FROM @B -- output you desire :)
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Really appreciate your help, but using the script for instance the script returns two entries which doesn't satisfy my requirement as the gap between two dates is less than 31 days, it should should fetch only first entry, the dates are INSERT INTO @A VALUES('1' ,'1' ,'1/15/2016')
                    ,('1' ,'2' ,'2/2/2016')

Comment: if you could provide me the exact sample data, i would give you exact query accordingly. :)

and the script returns 3 entries
'1'-------'1'---------'2016-01-01',
'1'-------'4'-------'2016-02-01',
'1'-------'5'-------'2016-07-01'

Comment: i have edited the question with your sql query & my requirements, you are a saviour :)

Comment: edited the answer, check the second modified query and how you would do it via procedure. :)

Comment: done, modified the answer, just like the way you want. :)

Comment: Excellent, that really solved my problem, such a relief. Thanks a ton :)